# why ionic 5 ngFor loop is not working on component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i have different components in my project.*ngFor is working in other components but it is not woking in one component.it is really strange can any one tell what i am doing wrong

```
@Component({  
 selector: 'app-age-picker', 
 templateUrl: './age-picker.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./age-picker.component.scss'],
})

export class AgePickerComponent implements OnInit {
   months: any = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
   constructor() { }
}
```

In HTML

`<div *ngFor="let month of months">month</div>`

Comment: check weather this component is imported in module

Comment: @YerrapotuManojKiran yes that was the problem.thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating it with `{{}}` brackets.
NgFor works with `{{}}`. Use brackets `{{month}}`

`<div *ngFor="let month of months">{{month}}</div>`

Comment: i didn't copy from the code.it was a typo when i typed here.thanks for the reply